# rails - curb: encoding issue sending request & token with "+"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, token, curb

I have a problem sending request to an external server, when the token has a "+" the other server don't recognize the request. I think it's a problem of encoding (sorry I'm newbie to rails) but I don't know what to do.

This is my code

```
        req = Curl::Easy.new do |curl| 
        curl.url = "https://blabla.com/bla?token=#{@token}"
        curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    end
    req.perform
    puts req.body_str
```

when token is similar to: S6ps1YSMC6xaRusfSH4aBg1RTm2/U1u1ng/hZSmGGTGX12AcL//Q33ri7Wlkl1Vjg4j/zDM=

it's ok, but when is:
HK+rKsYMTbs2fjN+pLfPIj5wcjZp3IVQWuK5jW0iN/wKfkVgsQAjQ5+A1RvUF1Lp0lgdf1M=

the response is 403 (forbidden).

I have searched in the docs but I have found nothing (https://github.com/taf2/curb).

Any ideas to force curl::easy to not convert the "+" in another thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uri encoding @token before sending the request. try the **'u'** method

```
>> u "HK+rKsYMTbs2fjN+pLfPIj5wcjZp3IVQWuK5jW0iN/wKfkVgsQAjQ5+A1RvUF1Lp0lgdf1M="
=> "HK%2BrKsYMTbs2fjN%2BpLfPIj5wcjZp3IVQWuK5jW0iN%2FwKfkVgsQAjQ5%2BA1RvUF1Lp0lgdf1M%3D"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have follow your line to solve the problem, at place for the u method I have used CGI::escape(@token) that have resolved the problem (for more info: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)